# SAS aggregation seconds into minutes

Tags: sas, aggregate-functions, mean

I have data structured where for every second (YY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS) I have actual car's speed. I want to aggregate my seconds into minutes (or 5, 10, 15 minutes) and have the average speed for that last minute (or 5,10,...).

Comment: Show us what you've tried already, example data, code, etc. SO isn't a code-on-demand service.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm sorry, but I have no idea how to start. Some told me Proc tabulate, but I'm not even sure it can work... i'm a real begginer...

Answer (score 0):

Use [proc timeseries](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_timeseries_sect002.htm), then choose your interval. For example, if you want to change it to 15 minute averages try

```
proc timeseries data = rawData output= minuteAvg;
id timestamp interval = Minute15 accumulate = avg;
run;
```

I've guessed the names of your time variable as you haven't supplied it. You can change the interval by suffixing the number of minutes to Minute (Minute1, Minute5, Minute10, etc.) or another interval keyword (Hour, Hour2, Hour12, Day, etc.).